# AmXYChart numberFormatter doesn't work for some graphs

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have created the jsfiddle which is representing the issue (http://jsfiddle.net/g44YG/1/).
Description: let's say we want to have two graphs (two sets of points) in our chart and since we have decided to use balloons (tooltips) we are going to use the number formatter to format the numbers which will appear in these balloons.

```
chart.numberFormatter = {
            precision : 1,
            decimalSeparator : '.',
            thousandsSeparator : ','
        };
```

And here is the data we use:

```
var chartData = [ {
            z : 1.17458,
            j : 2.17545
        }, {
            z : 5.17454,
            j : 4.174545
        }, {
            x : 3.45343,
            y : 1.55343
        }, {
            x : 5.53434,
            y : 4.51215
        } ];
```

And here is the code of two graphs:

```
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.xField = "z";
        graph.yField = "j";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.bullet = "round";
        graph.balloonText = "z:[[z]] j:[[j]]";
        chart.addGraph(graph);

var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.xField = "x";
        graph.yField = "y";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.bullet = "round";
        graph.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
        chart.addGraph(graph);
```

The problem is for the first graph (z,j) number formatter does not work when for the second graph(x,y) it works OK. You can understand what I mean looking on this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g44YG/1/.

Comment: strange... just a moment ago I tried to edit this demo http://www.amcharts.com/demos/scatter-chart/ and numberFormatter works well for both graphs

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is solved. All I had to change for the first graph is the next line

```
graph.balloonText = "z:[[z]] j:[[j]]";
```

I have changed it to

```
graph.balloonText = "z:[[x]] j:[[y]]";
```

And this graph started working fine.

Here what the documentation says about this property (balloonText):

> Balloon text. You can use tags like [[value]], [[description]],
>   [[percents]], [[open]], [[category]] or any other field name from your
>   data provider. HTML tags can also be used.

I think that this comment may be rather confusing to the reader. Would be great if someone here make this comment clear?